# ionic server connection unsuccessful when checking internet connection

Tags: networking, ionic-framework, server, connection

I'm developing on ionic but I get a problem when I'm checking if there's internet connection.

This is my code for checking if internet connection:

```
$scope.checkConnection = function() {
   if(navigator && navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type ===   'none') {alert('no conexion');}
   else{alert('conectado');}
};
```

I call it in index.html like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="checkNetworkController" ng-init="checkConnection()">
```

When I start the app I get:
**Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)**

If I don't call checkConnection everything works fine.
I've tried to reinstall the cordova network plugin and I have added in config.xml:

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

But nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

I use the same code

```
if(navigator && navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type === 'none')    
{alert('no conexion');}
else{alert('conectado');}
```

But instead on a function, I include it in the $ionicPlatform.ready(function() at the app.js and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information** Then `window.Connection` for Checking available internet.

```
if(window.Connection){
    if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
      $state.go("error");
        alert("offline")
       }else{
            console.log(navigator.connection.type);
              alert("online")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm already using the plugin. I tried your code, but it doesn't enter in the first if (window.Connection)

Comment: did u use this command ** cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information ** ?  check console.log(navigator.connection.type) ; and console.log(window.Connection) ; in run

Comment: yes, I used that command. I get navigator.connection is undefined and  [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
return new ErrorConstructor(message);  on ionic.bundle.js (line25000)

Comment: share ur console . put both as same in angular.run ()

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
 

return new ErrorConstructor(message);

 
ionic.bundle.js (línea 13438, col 12)
TypeError: navigator.connection is undefined
 

console.log(navigator.connection.type) ;

 
app.js (línea 13, col 3)

Comment: I solve the $apply error, now I only get  TypeError: navigator.connection is undefined console.log(navigator.connection.type) ;

Comment: on which device u r testing it ?

Comment: I'm testing on Android Studio with API 19 and Android 4.4

Comment: Test on your android device and check on gap debugger

Comment: Same problem on real device, it doesn't enter in the first if (window.Connection)

Comment: If it is not working then take a look of this http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/check-network-information-change-with-ionic-famework/                       ..... Work with ng-cordova which is wrapper ,

Comment: one more thing , check once that r u using latest plugin . reinstall that plugin after removing it by cordova plugin add **cordova-plugin-network-information** it would not be org .